# New bone added to the Rig does not affect mesh after weight painting/vertex groups

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, pose-mode

I am new to blender.  I have some background in 3dsMax. I am trying to create a rig for eyelids close and open. I rigged the body. But then when I add a new bone for the eyelid and manually weight paint it to the bone or use vertex groups, it still does not affect the region when I pose it. Nothing happens when I move the bone. Am I doing something wrong here?
I understand there are also expressions. But would like to have rig control. Is there a way to fix this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: One can't help you without having a look at the blend file

Comment: Check the new bone's settings in the properties editor in the bone tab.  Is "Deform" checked?  Usually when a properly weight painted bone doesn't move the mesh that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Select the bone in *Edit* or *Pose* mode and make sure that its *Deform* option is activated. If it still doesn't work, make sure that the *Armature* modifier visibilty is activated.

[image]